# Keep react-native application alive on android

Tags: react-native

I work on a mobile application and use MQTT (javascript paho client) for push notification. But after user or android close application ,MQTT socket has been disconnected and cannot receive notifications. So, I need to make a service to keep socket alive. How can I make a service by react-native?

Answer (score 3):

I am using [react-native-background-job](https://github.com/vikeri/react-native-background-job) for a similar use case. This library allows you to run a background job that will run periodically, but for this use case the important feature is that if you pass a `alwaysRunning` parameter when scheduling the job, the app will keep running in the background even if the user closes it.